# Converting C# Objects to Json format

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

(Edited) My asp.net core version is 2.0

I am new to programming.
I am currently trying to call Microsoft Graph to list all of the application objects in my Azure AD tenant and save them JSON files.

I am using the Microsoft Graph SDK. When I make the call, the results comes back as a collection of `Microsoft.Graph.Application` objects but I can't convert them to JSON.

I've tried to convert the result using `.ToString()`, but each object just becomes "Microsoft.Graph.Application".

Is there a good way to do this?

```
IConfidentialClientApplication daemonClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(daemonClient);
GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
GetApplicationList(graphServiceClient, log).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var applicationList = await graphServiceClient.Applications.Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: This is called Serialization. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+serialize+to+json for loads of information on this.

Comment: Look in to using the package `Newtonsoft.Json` from NuGet. It makes things very easy to turn json to objects and objects to json.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET Core 3.0, there is now a built-in [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json) set of classes which provides out-of-the-box JSON (de)serialization without a dependency on [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). It's a bit simpler, and doesn't support some more sophisticated scenarios, but it's also supposed to be faster for most cases. [Microsoft's documentation for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to) is quite good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't write which version of asp .net core you use.

In version 2.0 [Json Newtonsoft library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is used to handle json serialization/deserialization.

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```

In version 3.0 has been introduced new default library for handling json operations [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1), but you can change configuration to still use Newtonsoft. Example usage of the System.Text.Json.

```
string jsonString;
jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast);
// {
//  "Date": "2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00",
//  "TemperatureCelsius": 25,
//  "Summary": "Hot",
//  "DatesAvailable": ["2019-08-01T00:00:00-07:00",
//  "2019-08-02T00:00:00-07:00"],
//  "TemperatureRanges": {
//      "Cold": {
//          "High": 20,
//          "Low": -10
//      },
//      "Hot": {
//          "High": 60,
//          "Low": 20
//      }
//  },
//  "SummaryWords": ["Cool",
//  "Windy",
//  "Humid"]
// }
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I've successfully serialized the C# object to JSON using Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: I will attach my code for people who ran into the same question. `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(application);`